# Or syntax when parsing urls with regex & python

Tags: python, regex

Struggling with some regex here. I'll be looping through several urls but I cannot get the regex to how to recognize revenue or cost and grab the them both. Essentially the output would look something like this:

```
import re

url = ['GET /ca.gif?rb=1631&ca=20564929&ra=%n&pid=&revenue=224.00&cost=',
       'GET /ca.gif?rb=1631&ca=20564929&ra=%n&pid=&revenue=224.00',
       'GET /ca.gif?rb=1631&ca=20564929&ra=%n&pid=&revenue=224.00&cost=13']
values = []
for i in urls:
    values.append(re.search(r'(?<=revenue=)(.*?)(?=&|;)',url).group(0))

print values

[[224.00, ''],
 '224.00',
 [224.00, 13]]
```

Comment: I think the last list is your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `re.findall` since `re.search` returns only the first match.

```
>>> for i in url:
        values.append(re.findall(r'(?:\brevenue=|\bcost=)(.*?)(?:[&;]|$)', i))


>>> values
[['224.00', ''], ['224.00'], ['224.00', '13']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`urlparse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) to parse the URL, and [`urlparse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) to parse the query string.

```
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs

reqs = ['GET /ca.gif?rb=1631&ca=20564929&ra=%n&pid=&revenue=224.00&cost=',
        'GET /ca.gif?rb=1631&ca=20564929&ra=%n&pid=&revenue=224.00',
        'GET /ca.gif?rb=1631&ca=20564929&ra=%n&pid=&revenue=224.00&cost=13']

urls = [re.split(' +', s, 1)[1] for s in reqs]

kv = [parse_qs(urlparse(url).query) for url in urls]

values = [(e.get('revenue'), e.get('cost')) for e in kv]
# values = [{'revenue': e.get('revenue'), 'cost': e.get('cost')} for e in kv]
```

Sample output (`parse_qs` provides a list of values for every key, since the query may contain duplicate keys):

```
[(['224.00'], None), (['224.00'], None), (['224.00'], ['13'])]
```

The `values` line is not necessary. You can use the `kv` dict directly.

If you have to deal with invalid input, the list comprehension with `urls` and `kv` has to be rewritten as a loop:

- For `urls`, you need to check and filter out entries without HTTP method
- For `kv`, you need to add try catch for `urlparse` to catch invalid syntax.